# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" - error with arraylist in sub routine

Tags: vb.net, object, arraylist

`CustomersFound` is an `ArrayList` defined as follows:

```
Public CustomersFound As ArrayList
```

A **`NullReferenceException`** is thrown when I try to add to the collection.

```
CustomersFound.Add(Node)
```

The exact message states: ***"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"***.

I'm adding to the `ArrayList` in a public subroutine as follows:

```
Public Sub SearchTraverse(ByVal Node As Customer, Surname As String)
    ' Code to search for customers here...

    CustomersFound.Add(Node)
End Sub
```

Can anybody help me as to why I am getting this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Have you even "Googled" for the type of exception that is thrown: `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: your code simply declares the type but does not instance it (no `New`, no instance): `Public CustomersFound As NEW ArrayList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that `CustomersFound` does not exist. Check that whatever method you're using has actually created one. The code you have does not instantiate an ArrayList. Perhaps you should use:

```
Public CustomersFound As New ArrayList()
```

Comment: +1 The `NullReferenceException` is thrown when an object is accessed without having priorly being instantiated as per MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1